# Error in inserting an XMLTYPE column data into a Oracle 11g database more than 4KB

Tags: oracle11gr2, xmltype, webmethods

I am trying to insert a XML request data into a table where the size of the XML message is more than 4KB and I am receiving the error: 'ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column'. I am receiving the XML request data as part of a transaction as a string data and due to the server used (webMethods Integration server  9.0) I have a limitation of converting the data into another format. I have tried the following methods:

insert into testtable values (xmltype())

insert into testtable values (xmltype().getClobVal())

insert into testtable values (TO_CLOB())

The table schema is as given below:

```
desc testtable
Name    Null     Type      
------- -------- --------- 
XMLDATA NOT NULL XMLTYPE()
```

The insert to the table should also happen within a short time as the operation is executed for every request message that is coming to the server. Please help.

Comment: Not familiar with "webmethods", but it looks like the trouble is the fact that it binds your XML data in your `insert` statement as the (dreaded) `long` datatype. Either (a) try to force it to bind the value as BLOB/CLOB and use the `xmltype(:yourBindVariable)` constructor or (b) use a temp table with a `long` column, then `insert ... select` from the temp table to your target table or (c) use an anonymous PL/SQL block (instead of the pure `insert`) for server-side conversion of the `long` to an `xmltype`. Can't assume which of these is going to work, but it's at least something to start with.

Comment: Thanks @nop77svk - I have tried the `xmltype(:yourBindVariable)`  it didn't work. I will try out your suggestions (b) and (c), but since the database is not within my control I might not be able to proceed with that. I was hoping to handle the issue in the application code itself.

Comment: If you can't fiddle with the database, then the anonymous PL/SQL approach might work. I'm posting an answer for you with the code, since it requires code formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the above code a bit and it is working now, but I am not really sure why:

```
declare
    l_long          long;
    l_clob          clob;
begin
    l_long := :1;
    l_clob := TO_CLOB(l_long);
    insert into testtable values (xmltype(l_clob));
    dbms_lob.freetemporary(l_clob);
end;
```

This is working for XML type data above 4KB as well. @nop77svk - thanks for your guidance.

Comment: Good to see that it eventually worked. Needs a little cleanup, though ... Delete the `l_string` declaration and the `l_xmltype` declaration+assignment. You are doing XML DOM parsing of the input twice ... which does not go well with the performance efficiency you asked for.

Comment: And it might be a good thing to put `dbms_lob.freetemporary(l_clob);` below the `insert into testtable ...` statement.

Comment: @nop77svk - I have edited the code to include your suggestions. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This "anonymous PL/SQL block"-approach might work, but I'm not sure, since I don't have *webmethods* of my own to test it ...

Instead of

```
insert into testtable
values (xmltype(:1))
```

try running

```
declare
    l_long          long;
    l_string        varchar2(32767);
begin
    l_long := :1;
    l_string := l_long;
    insert into testtable values (xmltype(l_string));
end;
```

There might, however, be an issue with processing XML documents larger than 32767 (maybe even larger than 4000) chars.

Comment: I tried running the code directly on SQL Developer for XMLdata of size 5.44KB. I am getting a similar error as before. - `ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column
ORA-06512: at line 7
01461. 00000 -  "can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column"`

Answer (score 0):

By default everything in wM is defined as a string. But while using the adapter connection you need to check what is the input type. So for the field which has been defined as Long in DB you need to either pass a long object from wM or you need to make the input type for the field as string in adapter service. Also you need to check the size defined in the DB. If you suspect large size then set the field type in DB as CLOB instead.